# "Us versus them" - opposite of "noster"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary, word-request, pronouns

*Noster* can mean "one of us" in a symbolic way; L&S mentions that *noster eris* "you will be one of us" was a set expression for welcoming a deserter into the army, for instance.

The English opposite of this would be "one of *them*", but to my understanding Latin third-person pronouns are much weaker than their English equivalents. Would *eōrum* really have this connotation? Or would another word, such as *alius* or *alter*, fit better?

To put it differently: how best to really convey the sense of other-ness in the English expression "us versus them"? Not necessarily *hostēs*, but people who are most definitely **not** part of the same group as the speaker.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if "us and them" had the same opposing connotation in Latin than it has in English and other modern languages.
I think the connotation was weaker if it existed, so the point might not get across.

Instead, I might use the adjective *alienus* for outsiders.
For example:

> *Aut noster eris aut alienus!*
>   "You will be either one of us or one of them!"